# Investigate $f(x)=\log \sinh \left(x^{2}\right)-x^{2}$ for $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The following are given

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\log(x)} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\sinh(x)} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{x^2} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\exp(x)} = \infty$$

My problem is that I do not know how to figure out whether the first or the second term in the function "wins". I think it's called order. Which one has the highest order wins.

Comment: You know that $\sinh(x^2) \sim e^{x^2}/2$ as $x\to\infty$, meaning that $f(x) \sim \log\left(e^{x^2}/2\right) - x^2 \sim \ldots $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \ln\left(\sinh\left(x^2\right)\right)-x^2 \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{2}\right)-x^2 \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{2}\right)-\ln\left(e^{x^2}\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{2e^{x^2}}\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2e^{2x^2}}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2e^{2x^2}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\ln(2)$$

Comment: It's ln(1/2), you have an extra `-`.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: ... and you have wrong sign of exponent in the denominator.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Oh, man! This is turning into a bad day! Thanks for catching those typos! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: If we'll ever blow up the earth due to a computation error, it will be due to a sign error :o)

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts It's kind of you to say that. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Holy cow! That wasn't even a sign error! @Bladewood Thank you very much for your help!